# ember specifying ember todos demo templates as assets

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I tried converting the Ember Todos demo from the original source to where templates are specified in individual .handlebars files.

In other words I moved the todos/index template to 
assets/templates/todos/index.handlebars
and moved todos template to
assets/templates/todos.handlebars

This does NOT work... everything compiles and when I look at Ember.TEMPLATES it appears that the exact same templates have been created.

It renders nothing for the todos template.

If I change the file name of todos.handlebars to application.handlebars it renders okay, but other stuff is missing like the the number of completed items at the bottom.

--- update ---

I have found a work around.  If I rename the todos.handlebars template to foo.handlebars, and update the Todos route as follows, it works

```
Todos.TodosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('todo');
  },
  renderTemplate: function(controller) {
    this.render('foo', {controller: 'todos'});
  }
});
```

The following combinations DO NOT work:
1) calling the template file todos.handlebars and using this.render('todos'...)  (i.e. the file can't be named todos.handlebars
2) leaving off the controller specification in the render, or using the controller passed into the function.

Comment: Can you share the code somewhere?

Comment: Not sure... will to have to figure that out, but very simply i took the working demo, and simply moved the templates out of the .html file and into the separate template files in the assets directory.

Comment: If you want them in a separate file, you'll need some sort of build step. Do you have one?

Comment: This is a clean install of ember-rails following the instructions.  Note that the odd thing is does work sort of.  You just have manually set up everything in routes.